# Android SDK for AWS cognito userpool

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-userpools

We are using AWS Cognito userpool with Custom OIDC Provider. We tried AWS Amplify SDK for generating access tokens using the userpool, but looks like it does not support this. Is there any alternative SDK for Android using this setup to authenticate the user and get the access token. Most of the documentation and samples available are based on Identity Pool. But we are using the userpool.